# Best practice for processing a batch of sequential images with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, torchvision

I have a batch of sequential images each containing 5 frames with a shape of `(Batch, Sequence, Height, Width, Channel)`. Here how it looks like with a batch size of 32:

```
data.shape
> (32, 5, 256, 512, 3)
```

Now I want to apply some OpenCV and Torch operations on these images. Some examples for these are

```
cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

or `torchvision.transforms.compose` operation as:

```
midas_transformer
> Compose(
    <function transforms.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7ff5c5488a60>
    <midas.transforms.Resize object at 0x7ff5c547c0a0>
    <midas.transforms.NormalizeImage object at 0x7ff5c547c0d0>
    <midas.transforms.PrepareForNet object at 0x7ff5c547c130>
    <function transforms.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7ff5c5488af0>
```

Currently my solution is nested list comprehension:

```
new_image = np.array([[my_function(sequence) for sequence in batch] for batch in data])
```

My question is: What is the best practice to apply these operations on each image frame? Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For the pytorch operations, I would first `.reshape()` `data` into a `(32 * 5, 3, 256, 512)` tensor, then apply the transformation on this whole batch to fully take advantage of CPU/GPU parallelism, and finally reshape into a `(32, 5, 256, 512, 3)` tensor

Comment: Thank you, that was also one of my ideas, but the problem here is that these 5 images are sequential and this order should not be shuffled. I am not very sure if reshaping will preserve this order

Comment: @Asil You can check it works by comparing each packet of 5 images from the resized version to a packed of 5 images from the original:   `torch.equal(a[i], b[i*5:(i+1)*5].reshape(5, 256, 512))`  with `i in range(32)` and `a` and `b` the original and resized versions respectively